# Collection of values in android

Tags: android, json, object

I have Json object in format

```
{ "result": 
    { "name": "ram", "mark": "50" },
    { "name": "ram", "mark": "60" },
    { "name": "ram", "mark": "50" },
    { "name": "ram", "mark": "50" },
    { "name": "ram", "mark": "50" },
    { "name": "ram", "mark": "80" },
    { "name": "ram", "mark": "50" }
}
```

How do I sort the result into lists depending on the mark.

Please help..thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at GSON, it will do the parsing for you

Comment: I have no issue in parsing  , issue is in how to check marks value for equal and different set

Comment: As a note, the downvotes are because you didn't how any effort in solving the problem on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the notes. I have not more knowledge about this site thats why didn't notice.

Answer (score 0):

To do it on your own, without the help of any helper classes, libraries, etc. you can do it like this

Say you have your result of type `Object` parsed out into an object called `parsedObjects` which is an array containing you results

```
List<List<Objects>> sortedLists = new ArrayList<>();

// Loop through the array of parsed objects
for(Object parsedObject : parsedObjects){
    boolean match = false;  // flag to let us know if we found a match

    // Loop through our sorted lists, checking the first item
    // in the list (since all items in the list should have the same
    // mark) to see if the mark of the current parsed object matches
    // that of the already sorted object's mark
    for(List<Objects> sortedList : sortedLists){
        if(sortedList.get(0).mark.equals(parsedObject.mark)){
            sortedList.add(parsedObject);
            match = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If you didn't find a match in the loop, create a new list 
    // and add it to our list of object lists
    if(!match){
        List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        newList.add(parsedObject);
        sortedLists.add(newList);
    }
}

// Now sortedLists is a list of object lists, which is sorted by
// the objects' marks
```

This is just because you asked how to do it. There are a number of other, and more efficient ways. Maps, for example, would help streamline this.

```
Map<String, List<Object>> markMap = new HashMap<>();
for(Object parsedObject : parsedObjects){
    // If the map has a list with a matching mark key
    // get the list and add our object to it
    if(markMap.get(parsedObject.mark) != null){
        List<Object> sortedList = markMap.get(parsedObject.mark);
        sortedList.add(parsedObject);
    }
    // Else create a new list, add our object to the list
    // and set the key for the map to the object's mark
    else{
        List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        newList.add(parsedObject);
        markMap.put(parsedObject.mark, newList);
    }
}

// Now markMap is a map that contains a list of objects sorted
// by their mark. To get a list by the mark string key, all you have
// to do is call markMap.get([mark string key]);
```

There are a huge number of ways to do this, many of them likely more streamlined than these (this code itself can be cleaned up/shortened but I wanted to be explicit in what was going on), but this is just to get you started in your ventures.